# Facebook API - How to POST as Page not User - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post to my FB Page as my FB page.  The code below is posting to my page as myself(user) not as my Page.

I have the permission scope 'publish_pages' in my login call, not sure if I can link the token up to the postInfo function somehow.

var id;
      var token;

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });

    FB.login(function (response) {
      id = response.authResponse.userID;
      token = response.authResponse.accessToken;



      if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
          console.log(response.name);
          console.log(response.id);
          FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.url);
          });
        });

        FB.api('/me/accounts', function (response) {
          console.log(response.data[0].access_token);
          console.log(response.data[0].name);
          console.log(response.data[0].id);
          postInfo(response.data[0].access_token, response.data[0].id);

        });
      } else {
        alert("Login attempt failed!");
      }
    }, { scope: 'publish_pages' });

    function postInfo(token, id){
      FB.api(
          "/"+id+"/feed",
          "POST",
          {
              "message": "This is a test message"
          },
          function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
              /* handle the result */
            }
          }
      );
    }

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Use a page access token. Facebook documentation tells you how to get a page access token

Comment: Was missing the Page access token query string on my /id/feed call. FIXED